# Output field content for a product in Craft Commerce

Tags: templating, assets, plugin-craftcommerce

I have added the field "Product Image" to my products. The field is an "asset field" which enables me to upload an image for each product. The field handle is `productImage`.

How can I output this image in my template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to Craft!

A very basic piece of code for displaying your image would look like this (the if statement first checks if the field actually has an asset or not):

```
{% if product.productImage|length %}
    <img src="{{ product.productImage.first.getUrl() }}" />
{% endif %}
```

This quite simply outputs the image as it has been added in Craft, full size. Of course this isn't ideal as the images could be huge. That's why we have [Image Transforms](https://craftcms.com/docs/image-transforms), which allow you define the size of the images.

Here is the above code again, but updated to use a new transform we have created in Craft called 'Test Transform', with a handle of 'testTransform':

```
{% if product.productImage|length %}
    <img src="{{ product.productImage.first.getUrl('testTransform') }}" />
{% endif %}
```

Hopefully that gets you started. I'd recommend reading through the [Craft docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.assets) for using and templating asset fields.

Comment: I'd advise adding a `if product.productImage.first()|length` around those examples.  Otherwise if there is no image set on the product you'll get an exception raised.

Comment: @JeremyDaalder Good point, I've updated the answer.